# How do I group products into stores on woocommerce/wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm attempting to create a local library store in Wordpress using Woocommerce. The idea is to have multiple university campus libraries (actual buildings) and when the user selects the campus library they require, the store then goes to show the available products in the library. The closest example of what I'm trying to achieve is the just-eat.co.uk model (have a look at the site if you know the answer and may need a little more clarification). But that's pretty much it, the ability to group multiple products into different building names. I haven't changed any of the HTML to the Woocommerce store yet, but that essentially is the question I'm asking; what HTML/CSS is needed?

HTML (from archive.php):

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

        <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_archive_description hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>

    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use categories for your "buildings"? You can even have one book available in multiple buildings (categories) then.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood the question,

Hypothetically speaking
1. you want to setup 4 libraries (buildings).
2. You want to enter products (books) in these stores by availability.
3. Some of them can be in 2 buildings only, some of them in 3 buildings only. Means they are common in these buildings.

If these above is what you want to achieve, I have a simple solution.

1. Get this plugin WP all import which is free.
2. Make an Excel sheet of the products (books) and mention a column Libraries and save in CSV format.
3. In that column, mention the names of the building separated by a comma.
4. Now just import that file using the above plugin.
5. While you import it will ask you to put categories section of each product in the plugin window. 
   [image]
6. You just have to mention Libraries column and separated by a comma.
7. And start the import.
8. you can import thousands of books with each having their category mentioned on the frontend.